# boost::log::sources::basic_logger::open_record_unlocked ignores parameters

Tags: logging, boost, attributes

Looking at the boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp header, the basic_logger::open_record_unlocked is ignoring the arguments passed by basic_composite_logger.

```
template< typename ArgsT >
record open_record_unlocked(ArgsT const&)
{
    return m_pCore->open_record(m_Attributes);
}
```

When I pass attributes through BOOST_LOG_WITH_PARAMETERS those attributes never make it to the filters or sinks.

How is something so essential to the library be so wrong? How is this not happening to everyone? Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but the Boost code is incriminating. Here is a snippet of my code:

mylog.hpp

```
namespace Log
{

enum Severity
{
    SPAM,
    TRACE,
    VERBOSE,
    DEBUG,
    INFO,
    WARNING,
    ERROR,
    FATAL
};

namespace Attr
{

BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD(Tag, Severity);
BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD(Tag, Component);

}  //  namespace Attr

}  //  namespace Log
```

mylog.cpp

```
namespace SomeCode
{

namespace attr
{

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity,  Log::Attr::Tag::Severity::keyword_name(),  Log::Severity);
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(component, Log::Attr::Tag::Component::keyword_name(), std::string);

}  //  namespace attr

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::string& component)
    {
        m_Logger.add_attribute(attr::component.get_name(), boost::log::attributes::constant<attr::tag::component::value_type>(component));
    }

    void bar()
    {
        BOOST_LOG_WITH_PARAMS(m_Logger, (Log::Attr::Severity = Log::INFO)) << "Test";
    }

private:
    boost::log::sources::logger_mt m_Logger;
};

}  //  namespace SomeCode

int main()
{
    SomeCode::Foo foo("main");
    foo.bar();
    return (0);
}
```

The log shows my component attribute but not the severity, and it is also not available to filters.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you pass to `BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS` are *not* attributes. These are named parameters that are received and used by [logger features](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/sources.html). Each such parameter has a meaning specific to a given feature that expects it. For example, the [severity logger feature](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.severity_level_logger) accepts the `severity` parameter, which it interprets as the severity level of the logging record. The `BOOST_LOG_SEV` macro handles the named parameter internally, so you don't have to use `BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS` for that.

Your example should look something like this:

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_severity, "Severity", Log::Severity);
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_component, "Component", std::string);

namespace SomeCode
{

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::string& component)
    {
        m_Logger.add_attribute(a_component.get_name(),
            boost::log::attributes::constant<tag::a_component::value_type>(component));
    }

    void bar()
    {
        BOOST_LOG_SEV(m_Logger, Log::INFO) << "Test";

        // Or, equivalently:
        BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS(m_Logger, (boost::log::keywords::severity = Log::INFO)) << "Test";
    }

private:
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<Log::Severity> m_Logger;
};

} // namespace SomeCode
```

Note that you don't need the `BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD` declarations. The named parameter the logger expects is `severity`, regardless of the attribute value type, and the parameter keyword is already declared by the library.

Comment: Thank you. it was not obvious that the open_record function wasn't taking attributes exactly. That tripped me up.